# Can i use Request Segment as id?

Tags: php, laravel

im newbie in laravel (what im using now is 5.4). So i got error because of trying to use {{Request::segment()}} as id in my view. Here's detail about it

My View

```
<a href="/kategori/tambah_post_kategori/{{Request::segment(2)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-right:8px"></i>Add
</a>
```

My Route

```
Route::get('/kategori/tambah_post_kategori/{id_kategori}','Kategori@tambah_post_kategori');
```

Error

```
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace of the error? If so update your question with it.

Comment: Could you add the URL on which you're trying to access its 2nd segment ?

Comment: The url that i was using "http://localhost:8000/category/2", after click button "Add", change into this "http://localhost:8000/kategori/tambah_post_kategori/2". URL segment was getting by Request(2) but it can't to be an array. Thx for ur response @FouedMOUSSI

Comment: i think the stack trace is in Factory.php line 134. Thx for ur response @FelippeDuarte

Answer (score 0):

You may access to current `request` parameters using:

```
 ... href="/kategori/tambah_post_kategori/{{request()->id_kategori}}"
```

Comment: Still error like before. it wasn't an array laravel said. Thx for ur response btw